# ReadWrite locking for dynamic, scoped resources

Tags: java, concurrency

I am trying to design something that works pretty much like a java concurrent ReadWrite lock, but to control access amongst resources that may overlap with one another.
The idea is that

```
Operation mgr.startReadOperation(Scope scope) // acquires a read lock
Operation mgr.startEndOperation(Scope scope)  // acquires a writelock
operation.end()                               // release the lock
```

where startOperation should block iff another operation has acquired a lock on any scope otherScope such that

```
scope.overlaps(otherScope) == true
```

... with the usual behavior that concurrent reads are ok but write locks are exclusive.

I can envision how to do this with a single exclusive lock on a set of operations that I maintain manually: requestors await on a single condition if there is any overlapping operation under way, and operation.end() notifies all waiters.

However I wonder if there is a smarter design, in particular something that would leverage the "fairness" properties of the Java 7 ReadWriteLock implementation?

[Edit] I should have mentioned that the list of possible scopes is very large and dynamic. To help picture things a scope is an arbitrary collection of nodes in a resource tree hierarchy, where resources are created & deleted all the time. Two scopes overlap as soon as two of their nodes are identical or share a common ancestor.

Comment: Why **not** use `ReadWriteLock`, particularly `Map<Scope,ReadWriteLock>`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you want a hierarchy. Still, you can use a collection of `ReentrantReadWriteLock`s as backing for your data structure.

Comment: Hmmm... but do I create a meta lock to protect going through the internal collection - if so I don't seem to get fairness (everybody notifies a single exclusive meta lock)? Or does start try to acquire each lock it needs in turn (in a nested way) - but then if that fails after the 3rd lock I need to bubble up await on the two locks already acquired?

Comment: Well, you want get absolute fairness either way. And, in a tree structure, for safety, you would actually have to dig **down** (from the most common lock at the root to the most specialized one). One thing that might help clarify this: is that an abstraction *ab nihilo* or do you have a concrete scenario? In the latter case, it would pay to include that scenario in your question.

Comment: I have a very concrete scenario, the one described at the end of the question. Think of those resources as directories and files of a filesystem: with a root directory tmp and files a,b,c and d in tmp valid scopes could be: [tmp] , [tmp/a,tmp/c] , [tmp/a], [tmp/a,tmp/d] ... basically any combination of nodes.

Comment: So, to clarify, a lock on a node implies a lock on all its subnodes (e.g. lock(/tmp/a) implies lock(/tmp/a/suba) )? And your hierarchy is actually a tree (no cycles)?